# Keep block style code spacing in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

How would one achieve to keep IntelliJ from removing spaces in Python (or any language for that matter) in areas where spaces serve a specific purpose of readability, such as repetitive assignments of many values.

[image]

is how I like it and I think many vim users agree that this is the way to go.

However, this is what IntelliJ makes out of it
[image]

The issue is specifically interesting with language such as python where spaces can (but do not have to) impact the programs flow.

I am also aware that it is rather difficult to define when spaces should be compacted (i.e. when only one of the 4 lines above are present) and when they should be kept.
I guess some heuristic approaches would work, this however wouldn't really be a 100% on-spot lintable situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like your idea, but don't see how to achieve that within the Editor Settings.

An ugly alternative that does work, but "pollutes" your source, is to **Enable formatter markers in comments** on this screen: **File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style**:

[image: reformat1]

After choosing that option you can selectively create blocks of code that will be ignored by IDEA when it formats the code:

```
// @formatter:off
String s1 = "Arkansas"      + ".";
String s2 = "Maine"         + ".";
String s3 = "Massachusetts" + ".";
String s4 = "Ohio"          + ".";
// @formatter:on
```

You could also raise a bug report with [JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=reformat): "*Provide an option to allow multiple embedded spaces in source code*". That should be fairly straightforward for them to implement: just don't replace multiple embedded spaces by a single space when reformatting.

Comment: Good answer (that there is none as of right now but guide to get it to work). I will create a ticket and come back here if they update it.

Comment: I created a [ticket with jetbrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186577)

Comment: @pascalwhoop Cool. Just FYI, there are plugins already available for what you want ("code alignment") with Visual Studio, Notepad++ and Sublime. See http://www.codealignment.com/Details.html . Let's hope JetBrains implement your idea.